# In Jekyll, how to show "posts from last week"

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm not sure to get the liquid syntax to help me pull posts that were published during the same week as the build date. Is that possible?

There are simpler ways to get a list of recent posts, but this approach would be useful for my project. I've tried several things I found by searching but no joy yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46683085/4731921) works, but doesn't span years.
>
> So I utilized the concepts and came up with a simpler and more flexible solution for filtering for a `timeframe` (which can be any variable time span of seconds, hours, days, weeks, or months). My solution has fewer variables, and less logic.

Liquid `date/time` uses unix timestamp (`%s = seconds since 1970`). So I kept the `timeframe` in seconds and do the conversion for the length of time. `86400 =  1 day`, `604800 =  1 wk`, `2678400 = 31 days`, ... and so on.

The code also assumes your posts use `last_modified_at` in your post frontmatter. You could substitute for `post.date` if you're not.

### Simple Solution

[image: Calendar Icon]

**List posts within last week**

```
{% assign timeframe = 604800 %}

{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign post_in_seconds = post.last_modified_at | date: "%s" | plus: 0 %}
  {% assign recent_posts = "now" | date: "%s" | minus: timeframe  %}

  {% if post_in_seconds > recent_posts %}
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Alternative

[image: Calendar Icon]

**List posts within timeframe and flag new or modified**

This code will list all posts to within a limit and flag an posts as new or modified  in `timeframe`.  Length of list is limited to `maxposts`. **Note:** css class is designed to utilize Bootstrap, remove/edit to your liking.

- `timeframe`  2419200 = seconds in 4 weeks
- `maxposts` = 10
- `label_FOOBAR` just clean way to handle html with liquid

**Example Results with new/modified flags & dates**

[image: Results]

**Code**

```
{% assign timeframe = 2419200 %}
{% assign maxposts = 10 %}
{% assign date_format = site.minima.date_format | default: "%m/%d" %}

<ul class="post-list text-muted list-unstyled">
{% for post in site.posts limit: maxposts %}
  {% assign post_in_seconds = post.last_modified_at | date: "%s" | plus: 0 %}
  {% assign recent_posts = "now" | date: "%s" | minus: timeframe %}
  {% assign post_updated = post.last_modified_at | date: date_format %}
  {% capture post_date %}<small>{{ post.date | date: date_format }}</small>{% endcapture %}

  {% if post_in_seconds > recent_posts %}
  {% capture label_new %}<span class="label label-primary">new</span>{% endcapture %}
    {% if post.last_modified_at > post.date %}
      {% assign label_new = '' %}{% comment %}Clear NEW if modified{% endcomment %}
      {% capture label_updated %}<span class="label label-info">Updated <span class="badge">{{ post_updated }}</span></span>{% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <li>
    <h4>{{ post_date }}
      <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
        {{ post.title | escape }}</a> {{ label_new }}{{ label_updated }}
      </h4>
  </li>
  {% assign post_date = '' %}
  {% assign label_updated = '' %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Before even giving this answer a second thought, consider the fact that, at the very least the first part of this answer doesn't really work, because jekyll is a *static* site generator and therefore the shown posts are relative to the last build date, which may not be the same as current date.
>
> The second part of the answer goes a bit deeper into the idea of actually generating a list of "recent posts", rather than "posts from last week".

To basically explain the code in words: First we get `current year` and `current week`, then we loop through every post and compare `current year` and `current week` to the `week` and `year` of the post. If  they match, the post is shown.

**Show — Build Week:**

[image]

```
{% assign currentYear = site.time | date: "%Y" %}
{% assign currentWeek = site.time | date: "%W" %}

{%- for post in site.posts -%}
    
    {% assign postYear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
    {% assign postWeek = post.date | date: "%W" %}
    
    {%- if currentYear == postYear and currentWeek == postWeek -%}
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    {%- endif -%}
    
{%- endfor -%}
```

**Show — Build  Day and 6 Days Prior:**

[image]

```
{% assign currentYear = site.time | date: "%Y" %}
{% assign currentDay = site.time | date: "%j" | plus: 0 %}
{% assign currentDay_minus_week = site.time | date: "%j" | minus: 7  %}

{%- for post in site.posts -%}
    
    {% assign postYear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
    {% assign postDay = post.date | date: "%j" | plus: 0 %}
    
    {%- if currentYear == postYear and postDay > currentDay_minus_week and postDay <= currentDay  -%}
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    {%- endif -%}
    
{%- endfor -%}
```

---

In an effort to sort of salvage this answer, though it already kind of veered off course.... I wrote this code with similar logic, but this time it gets the `year` and `week` of the latest post and shows all posts posted that year and that week.

This would be bulletproof in terms of showing something even if you keep building the site without making new posts. But it also just shows only one post, if your last post is the only post posted that week, which may be a bit dumb...

On the other hand, the simplest method for showing "recent posts" is probably just using the `limit` and limit recent posts to like last 5 posts or something like that: `{%- for post in site.posts limit: 5 -%}`

**Show — Latest Post Week:**

[image]

```
{% assign latestPost_year = site.posts.first.date | date: "%Y"  %}
{% assign latestPost_week = site.posts.first.date | date: "%W"  %}

{%- for post in site.posts -%}
    
    {% assign postYear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
    {% assign postWeek = post.date | date: "%W" %}
    
    {%- if latestPost_year == postYear and latestPost_week == postWeek -%}
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    {%- endif -%}
    
{%- endfor -%}
```

**Show — Latest Post Day and 6 Days Prior**

[image]

```
{% assign latestPost_year = site.posts.first.date | date: "%Y"  %}
{% assign latestPost_day = site.posts.first.date | date: "%j" | plus: 0  %}
{% assign latestPost_day_minus_week = site.posts.first.date | date: "%j" | minus: 7  %}

{%- for post in site.posts -%}
    
    {% assign postYear = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
    {% assign postDay = post.date | date: "%j" | plus: 0 %}
    
    {%- if latestPost_year == postYear and postDay > latestPost_day_minus_week and postDay <= latestPost_day  -%}
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    {%- endif -%}
    
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: This requires Jekyll to build daily. That is not a very realistic scenario.

Comment: I still like the code. It is good to get roughly the right posts in the HTML or when you use a cron to build daily (using Travis CI). With Travis CI and some little tweaks to this code you can also schedule posts (using the 'future' option in Jekyll).

Comment: I think there is still some value to this answer. It does kinda work... Depending on what you want from this list of posts and how you name it. —
 If you updated the site last time like, let's say a year ago, this lists of posts would contain "recent posts" relative to the last update (build date). Then again, as it is, it could fail if you keep making like stylistic changes to the site and building it without making any new posts...

Comment: I've revised my question for clarity. What I meant by "today" or "now" is the current build date. Essentially I'm looking for a way to show posts within 7 days of the build date.

Comment: @DylanKinnett Because the code didn't exactly do what you wanted, I added some more code that actually does do what you want and I also added images to illustrate a bit better how each of these works. I feel it's worth saying it again... Using the code that compares `build date` against `post date` has potential to show nothing if it's been more than a week since your last post and you build the site again after adjusting the layout or like adding a new page or anything that isn't a new blog post. The code that compares `latest post date` against `post date` is more bulletproof in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

You never know when Jekyll builds, so Jekyll should output a big(ger) list of posts. You can use the code of Joonas for this. Then you should use javascript to hide the non-relevant posts (those older than one week).

This can easily be done by adding a custom attribute to your list, like this:

```html
<li date="{{ post.date }}">{{ post.title }}</li>
```

Use jQuery (or vanilla js) to hide old posts:

```javascript
// loop through all list items with a date
$('li[date]').each(function(){
  // create a postDate in a date object
  var postDate = new Date($(this).attr('date'));
  // create an object with the date of one week ago
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
  oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
  // compare dates and hide old posts
  if(postDate<oneWeekAgo) $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Although this looks like a good approach, I think I would prefer a jekyll-only solution like the one Joonas described.

Comment: There is not such a thing as a Jekyll only approach to this. Jekyll sites are like pre pressed magazines. You never know when they will be read. The only exception to this, requires a cron job that rebuilds your site every day.