# How do I compare date in front-matter to site.date

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my Jekyll site, I have a collection `talks` that has a property in the front matter called `startDate`. I've formatted `startDate` in the actual front matter to `%Y-%m-%d`, so my front matter looks like this:

```
---
startDate: 2017-10-29
---
```

I'd like to show a section called **Upcoming Talks** if there are any `startDate`s that are after `site.time`. So far I have this:

```
{% assign currentDate = site.time | date: "%Y-%m-%d" %}
```

In a `for` loop, I can print `talk.startDate` and `currentDate` and show the values for each and they're in the same formate. But what I can't do is compare them. I'd really like to do this:

```
{% assign upcoming = site.talks | where_exp: "startDate", "startDate > currentDate" %}`

{% if upcoming.size > 0 %}
  <h1>Upcoming talks</h1>
  ...
{% endif %}
```

But when I get `size` for both `upcoming` and `past` (which is the same as `upcoming` but where `startDate < currentDate`), they both evaluate to 0. This tells me the dates aren't actually comparing in my filter.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this post: [In Jekyll, how to show "posts from last week"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672231/in-jekyll-how-to-show-posts-from-last-week). They try to do the same (only in the past and not in the future). Note that what you are trying to do requires Jekyll to build daily. That is not a very realistic scenario. A [javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46683059/2397550) would work better.

The javascript solution requires you to add a custom attribute to your list, like this:

```
{% for talk in upcoming %}
  <li date="{{ talk.startDate }}">{{ talk.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Then, use jQuery (or vanilla js) to hide old posts:

```
// loop through all list items with a date
$('li[date]').each(function(){
  // create a postDate in a date object
  var startDate = new Date($(this).attr('date'));
  // compare dates and hide old posts
  if(startDate<Date.now()) $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I can build the site daily with a cron job, so I'll use similar to the first suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @i7nvd Just out of curiosity: how do you run/configure your cron?

Answer (score 0):

The unspoken question is: How to compare date's in jekyll or liquid?

This was the easiest solution I could come up with:

```
{%- assign buildTimeInSecondsInEpoch = site.time | date: "%s" | plus: 0 -%}
```

This creates an integer variable that can be compares against. For example:

```
{%- assign pagesForPublishing = "" | split: "" -%}
{%- for ape in site.pages -%}
    {%- assign pageDateInSecondsInEpoch = ape.date | date:"%s" | plus: 0 -%}
    {%- if pageDateInSecondsInEpoch < buildTimeInSecondsInEpoch -%}
        {%- assign pagesForPublishing = pagesForPublishing | push: ape -%}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Also, Jekyll will not process posts with a date in the future, to allow this use the `--future` option (on build or serve).

Page files will be processed by jekyll regardless of date.