# Liquid filter by date (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to filter posts by specific dates in Jekyll. For example, I want to filer all posts posts today, in the past 30 days and everything before that.

However I'm running into a couple of issues:

1. How can I get the current date, starting at 00:01AM
2. How do I get the current date, and subtract 30 days
3. How can I use `where_exp` to filter by this date

Currently I tried to do something like this, but this converts the date into a string, and can't be used in the `where_exp`:

```
{% capture thirty_days_ago %}{{'now' | date: '%s' | minus: 2592000 }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign last_30_days_posts = site.posts | where_exp:"post", "post.posted_on > thirty_days_ago" %}

Liquid error (line 22): comparison of Time with String failed in index.html
```

I could do a simple check when looping over the posts, but would prefer using a filter before this.

```
{% capture thirty_days_ago %}{{'now' | date: '%s' | minus: 2592000 }}{% endcapture %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% capture post_date %}{{ post.posted_on | date: '%s' | plus: 0 }}{% endcapture %}

    {% if job_date > thirty_days_ago %}
        {% include components/job.html job=job %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672231/in-jekyll-how-to-show-posts-from-last-week

Comment: @BradWest Which is my existing solution, however I'm wondering if it can be done when filtering the array.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at a solution; I ended up writing a custom filter:

```
def last_month_filter(posts)
    now = DateTime.now
    today = DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0, 0, now.zone)
    target = today - 30

    posts.select do |post|
        postedOn = post.data['posted_on'].to_datetime

        if postedOn < today && postedOn > target
            post
        end
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
{% assign last_30_days = site.posts | last_month_filter | sort:"posted_on" | reverse %}
```